# How to fix 'Could not load file or assembly System.IO.Packaging, Version=4.0.3.0' in a .net standard 2.0 project

Tags: c#, winforms, openxml, .net-standard-2.0, system.io.packaging

I am trying to process a word document. For that, I installed the DocumentFormat.OpenXml NuGet package. It installed following dependencies:

- DocumentFormat.OpenXml
- System.IO.Packaging (4.5.0)
- System.Runtime.Serialization

[image: Here is the Screen shot]

As soon as it hit the code where I am processing the word document. It throws this error "Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Packaging, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

I have tried the following things so far:

- Try to manually add a reference of System.IO.Packaging to CSPROJ file but that didn't work and I got the same error.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" Version="2.9.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IO.Packaging" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.Common" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.6.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

- I tried to add "WindowsBase" nuget package but it displayed a conflict:

```
The type 'Package' exists in both 'System.IO.Packaging, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

The error is complaining about version 4.0.3.0 but nuget added version 4.5.0 of System.IO.Packaging DLL. How can I fix that?

Comment: Use binding redirect to redirect old references to use the new assembly  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/bindingredirect-element

Comment: Also currently there is a bug in WinForms projects. If you reference a net standard dll from the winforms project the dll won't get copied in the bin folder on build.

Comment: install the System.IO.Packaging in prerelease version 4.6.0-preview6.19303.8 before trying to install DocumentFormat.OpenXml

Comment: @magicandre1981... Getting the same error : Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Packaging, Version=4.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: activate [AutoGenerateBindingRedirects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection)

Comment: Github issue: https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX/issues/226

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the reference to `System.IO.Packaging (4.5.0)` and then try adding the "WindowsBase" nuget package

or

Try

`Update-Package –reinstall System.IO.Packaging`

Comment: I don't know how to remove "System.IO.Packaging" reference. As it is installed as part of the OpenXml dependency.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I installed WindowsBase from nuget. Then removed WindowsBase package. Then noticed that OpenXml was removed somehow. Then installed OpenXml again the latest version 2.20 and it started working.
Now IO.Packaging is under OpenXml package.

[image]

Edit: Also .net target framework got updated.
[image]