# Installed DocumentFormat.OpenXML via Nuget but getting "Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Packaging'"

Tags: c#, nuget, openxml-sdk

I installed `DocumentFormat.OpenXML` via Nuget so that I can manipulate Excel files.

I am testing with this code:

in `Program.cs`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExcelWatcher.ExcelDataExtractor xtr = new ExcelWatcher.ExcelDataExtractor();
            string data=xtr.getData(@"C:\Users\usrname\Documents\test.xlsx");
            Console.WriteLine(data);
        }
```

in `ExcelDataExtractor.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;


namespace ExcelWatcher
{
    public class ExcelDataExtractor
    {    
        public string getData(string workbookPath)
        {
            try
            {
                SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(workbookPath,false);
                return string.Empty;          
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.ToString();
            }
        }
}
```

But when, in `Program.cs`, the `xtr.getData()` call occurs, I get this error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Packaging, Version=4.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

as an unhandled exception.

I have a reference for the `WindowsBase` assembly enabled.

I looked at some other StackOverflow questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56875068/how-to-fix-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-io-packaging-version-4-0-3-0).  But when I tried running this in the Package Manager CLI:

```
update-package -reinstall System.IO.Packaging
```

I got this error:

```
update-package : 'System.IO.Packaging' was not installed in any project. Update failed.
```

But `System.IO.Packaging` is showing as one of the references I have enabled.

What's wrong with how I'm using OpenXML?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to install a previous version of `System.IO.Packaging`:

```
Install-Package System.IO.Packaging -Version 5.0.0
```